# IOS: create UIs programmatically or use Interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

we are building a little bigger mobile app in iOS. we need separate the components. there are two voices in team:

1. use the interface builder, it is OK.
2. programmatically, we can be good if any errors.

is there any person who involved this and have experiences can share some hints?

Comment: Voting to close as not appropriate. You'll have people who like using IB and those who prefer to do it in code. It'll just be opinions. There are some cases where the choice is obvious, but just asking for a general guideline is a poor question.

Comment: 1. we have a 8 android persons; 15M size of the APP(right now,bigger later), we need to move on iOS but we do not have ios experience; 
2. i am asking the practical experiences, not the general guideline, not theoretical..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had an app of size nearly 20MB at first. Initially it was designed programmatically (not even a single xib file). Recently we re-designed our app with xib. It increased our app size upto 25 MB. Additional 5MB added for xib files in resources.

Our app is an universal app (iPhone and iPad). So we need to have separate xib for iPhone and iPad.

So choose according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As i think there both have advantages and disadvantages

By Interface Builder

Advantage

*) You can prepare views very fast as compare to programmatically

Disadvantage

*) You can't have access of memory management for created views.

By Programmatically

Advantage

*) you can manage memory of created view by your self.

Disadvantage

*) It takes much time to prepare views as compared to interface builder

Comment: why this: "You can't have access of memory management for created views"? as far as i know, you can, if you follow the apple rules

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I chose to use Interface Builder, it easy to use and it's really a great tool. Moreover, even if you use IB you will be able to interact with the UI in your code (connecting you UI component to the IB , with the IBOutlet ;) )

Answer (score 0):

In my Point of view, i prefer to programmatically, because its give you more controlling in terms of rework or adding component.